# jQuery Ajax Call - Response StatusDescription Charset

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I started using the Response.StatusDescription to put error messages to the user on my Ajax calls (see code below)

The problem is with encoding. The response message comes with a problem on the accented letters (see AJAX call below).

It works fine on my PC, but once published to the server I start experiencing this problem.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
public JsonResult MyAction(int variable)
{
    if (variable > 0)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
    else
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unused;
        Response.StatusDescription = "Dados Inválidos"; //notice the 'á' on the message
    }
    return Json(true);
}
```

And my Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    url: '/testUrl/MyAction',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
        variable: myVal
    }
})
    .done(function()
    {
        //Do something
    })
    .fail(function(error, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        var msg = error.statusText; //The message received is: "Dados InvÂilidos"
        if (error.status !== 306) //HttpStatusCode.Unused
            msg = 'Error occurred';

        this.dialogShowError(msg);
    });
```

UPDATE:
This is the response header that I receive:

[image]

The problem seems to happen only on Ajax Requests. I've made a test on a Regular ActionResult and the StatusDescription is set fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
```

My hunch is the HTTP response header has the wrong charset.

Comment: I've added your suggestion but I am still getting the same problem. See my update with the response headers.